# Correct annotation for description of RsponseDto's fields

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am developing REST API. I use Sparkjava for that. Also, I am creating API Documentation. I use the `Swagger` and `open API` specifications for that.

I created this response:

```
@Data
public class OrderDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int count;
}
```

And it was converted to this response:

```
components:
  schemas:
    OrderDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
        count:
          type: integer
```

[image]

Now I want to add a description for some fields. But I don't know how to do it. I can do it manually:

```
components:
  schemas:
    OrderDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
        name:
          type: string
          description: name description
        count:
          type: integer
          description: count description
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Which annotation should I add to the response for that? I tried this:

```
io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty
```

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this

```
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;

@Data
@ApiModel(value = "OrderDto ", description = "A model representing some order")
public class OrderDto {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int count;
}
```